# UPDATE sql not updating

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having an issue with this UPDATE sql, for some reason it's not updating table NOMI. I'm not getting any type of error. I'm updating this table with values from another table which is where the `Me.(...)` is getting their values. When I do `Debug.Print` I'm getting this:

`UPDATE NOMI SET workername = 'Bob', dateassigned = #5/27/2015 8:52:52 PM#, actiondate = #5/30/2015 11:56:43 AM#, caseid = 'BO09999', lastname = 'Smith', firstname = 'Jane', Program = 'Awesome', language = 'English', Status = 'Unprocessed' WHERE ((IsNull([caseid]))<>False)`

Here is the code:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE NOMI SET workername = '" & Me.workername & "', 
dateassigned = #" & Me.dateassigned & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, 
caseid = '" & Me.caseid & "', lastname = '" & Me.lastname & "', 
firstname = '" & Me.firstname & "', Program = '" & Me.program & "', 
language = '" & Me.language & "', Status = '" & Me.Status & "' 
WHERE ((IsNull([caseid]))<>False)"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: How many rows satisfy the `WHERE` condition? `SELECT Count(*) AS row_count FROM NOMI WHERE ((IsNull([caseid]))<>False)`

Comment: Note if the table is empty, you need an `INSERT` instead of an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Hi @HansUp you're right. I adjusted my code into an INSERT query and that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
WHERE ((IsNull([caseid]))<>False)
```

Basically means:

```
WHERE caseid is null
```

Which might not be true for any row in the table.  Certainly if `caseid` is a primary key, it cannot be `null`.

Comment: Hi @Andomar, actually `caseid` is Null, This is a new table, so there is no data on the table yet. I'm adding this data onto table NOMI.

Comment: Oh!  Well, `update` is for updating existing rows.  If you're trying to insert a new row, use the `insert` command. Like `insert into YourTable (col1, col2) values 'value1', 'value2';`

Comment: You're correct. I'm writing the `INSERT` query now, but can use `Me.(...)` in an INSERT query like this?